Approximate solution to nonlinear (algebraic) first-order ODE
I would like to analytically solve the following non-linear ODE:
\begin{equation}
\frac{de}{dt} = \frac{\left(1-e^2\right)^{3/2}}{e^{29/19} \left(304 + 121 e^2\right)^{1181/2299}} \text,
\end{equation}
with $e: \mathbb{R}_{\geq0} \to (0, 1)$ and some initial condition $e(0) = e_0$. My end goal is to obtain an analytical expression for the function $e$ which is not necessarily exact, but (subjectively) approximates the solution decently. (This equation is inspired by the evolution of binary black-hole orbits in General Relativity). A numerical plot of the system, departing from $e_0 \approx 0$ (without loss of generality) can be seen here. The system never reaches $e(t) \to 1$, only asymptotically as $t \to \infty$.
Clearly, a formal solution to the above ODE is given by inverting:
\begin{equation}
t = \int_{e_0}^e \frac{u^{29/19} \left(304 + 121 u^2\right)^{1181/2299}}{\left(1-u^2\right)^{3/2}} du \text.
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, this integral cannot seemingly be solved in terms of elementary or other known functions. Furthermore, once solving such integral, I would require inverting the equation to obtain $e(t)$.
To clarify, my goal does not require specifically to solve the above integral but rather to obtain a decent solution for $e(t)$ using some approximation method, by which I mean:

The solution $e(t)$ is explicitly expressed in terms of t (the simpler the better);
Approximates well at least locally around the initial condition; (globally is better!)
It is bounded in the interval $[0,1]$ for all $t$; (values outside this range are "non-physical")

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed, respecting all three conditions: ideas of methods to apply, and if there are general techniques for solving this kind of problem.

What I have done so far:

Observe that at $e \to 0$ the derivative is unbounded. At first order around zero $e$ behaves like $e \sim \left( \frac{48}{19 \times 304^{1181/2299}} t \right)^{48/29}$. This inspires the following change of variables $u = e^{29/48}$, which removes the zero-poles from the denominator of the ODE but did not seem to help much other than that.
I have been attempting to find a series solution that works well both in the neighbourhood of $e \sim 0$ and for other values of $e_0$. The following expression seems helpful in order to capture the asymptotic behaviour: $$ e(t) = 1 - \exp{\big(-\lambda(t)\big)}$$ with $\lambda(0) = -\log{(1-e_0)}$ and $\lambda(+\infty) = +\infty$. I have numerically fitted the first terms of a "Puisseau" series expansion: $\lambda = -0.451284 \, t^{19/48} - 0.070133 \, t^{19/24}$ when $e_0 \to 0$. I have plotted such solution here. It would be nicer to somehow match the coefficients analytically (the first coefficient is easy, it comes from the first order solution previously discussed).


A starting idea is to let $e(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 ...  a_k t^k $ up to some polynomial order $k$. Then we can equate $\frac{de}{dt}$ with the $(k-1)^{st}$ order polynomial expansion of $\frac{\left(1-e^2\right)^{3/2}}{e^{29/19} \left(304 + 121 e^2\right)^{1181/2299}}$ resulting in $k+1$ equations for the $k+1$ unknowns. I wonder if this ends up converging to something well-enough behaved for sufficiently large $k$.

dont call it $e$,  you're bound to get confused with $exp$

I would try and expand the rhs in terms of $e$ or some rational power of $e$, and then Pade approximate the expansion, keeping the Pade rational function to be one that can be integrated

Shouldn't it be $e{:}, \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \left( 0,, 1 \right)$? If $e{:}, \mathbb{R}^{+} \to \left( 0,, 1 \right)$ then $e\left( 0 \right)$ would not exist because $0 \notin \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

@SidharthGhoshal thanks, your approach might be equivalent to Claude's answer below, if fractional powers of t are used. I tried something similar, but this $e$ is unbounded when t grows large. I wonder if I could adapt it to search for an exponential solution $e(t) = 1 - exp(- \lambda(t))$, which has the advantage of staying within [0, 1]... (for positive $\lambda$)

@user619894 that's indeed a possible mishap. Unfortunately it's a cemented convention in the literature, $e$ describes the "eccentricity" of elliptical orbits. In physics we tend to use `\mathrm{e}' to represent & differentiate Euler's number.

@user619894 that's helpful insight. I will see what I can obtain from your method.

@KevinDietrich yes, you're right. I was more habituated with the convention $\mathbb{R}^+$ for non-negative and $\mathbb{R}^+_*$ for positive reals but your suggested notation avoids any ambiguity. I have edited the question to use it.

I'd say my approach is probably strictly inferior unless by some fluke those partial taylor approximations meet your constraints despite the fact the proper taylor series does not

Making the poblem more general
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\left(1-x^2\right)^{3/2}}{x^{a}\, \left(b + c\, x^2\right)^{d}} 
\end{equation}
cannot be integrated.
However, switching variables
\begin{equation}
\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{x^a \left(b+cx^2\right)^d}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{3/
   2}} 
\end{equation} can be solved but the result is given in terms of the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.
Using your values for $(a,b,c,d)$
$$t+C=k\, x^{48/19}
   F_1\left(\frac{24}{19};\frac{3}{2},-
   \frac{1181}{2299};\frac{43}{19};x^2,
   -\frac{121 x^2}{304}\right)$$ with $$k=\frac{19\times 19^{1181/2299}}{6\times2^{2173/2299}}\sim 7.46395$$
Expanded around $x=0$ and letting $u=\frac t k +c$
$$u=x^{48/19}\,\Bigg(1+\frac{29535x^2}{31046}+\frac{216378255
   x^4}{258556864}+\frac{18164430195 x^6}{24087491072}+\frac{1920648415789053 x^8}{2782586968637440}+O\left(x^{10}\right)  \Bigg)$$
Using power series reversion
$$x=u^{19/48}-\frac{9845u^{19/16}}{26144}+\frac{8575891605
   u^{95/48}}{42377541632}-\frac{438780667379645
   u^{133/48}}{3323755345281024}+\frac{1803619323750028338111
   u^{57/16}}{17958560347718932234240}+\cdots$$
Let $u=v^{48/19}$ to get
$$x=v-\frac{9845
   v^3}{26144}+\frac{8575891605v^5}{42377541632}-\frac{438780667379
   645v^7}{3323755345281024}+\frac{1803619323750028338111
   v^9}{17958560347718932234240}+O\left(v^{11}\right)$$

Thank you for the clear solution. This works great locally when $x \approx 0$, but can it be applied to other initial conditions? I have computed the series around another expansion point $x_0 \neq 0$, but in such case I obtain a power series with integer coefficients. Is there a way to combine / get an expansion valid for any $x_0 \in [0, 1)$?

@Christopher. No, unless you want  the coefficient depend on Appell hypergeometric function of two variables..

I understand... how unfortunate. Plotting the series you provided, it seems to converge only for $t \simeq 1$, which corresponds to $e \approx 0.76$. For values of $t > 1$, it explodes no matter how many terms I compute...

For now, I shall be using my "hack", which consists of applying a change of variables $x = 1 - \exp{(-\lambda)}$, and computing a series solution for $\lambda$ around $0$ (in the same spirit you do for $x$). This has the advantage of being asymptotically equal to your solution near $x = 0$ but also bounded for $t \to \infty$.

*Correction: $x$ seems to converge for $t \leq 1$

@Christopher you can always Pade the series and possibly expand the convergence
